# How to fix datatable header vertically without using scrollY?

Tags: jquery, datatable, fixed-header-tables

I want to fix datatable header when scrolling page without using scrollY property just like https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/ datatable.

Do anyone know about this ?

Answer (score 0):

source:

```
$('#main_table_countries_' + val).dataTable({

            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "scrollX": true,
            "order": [

                [1, 'desc']
            ],
            "sDom": '<"bottom"flp><"clear">',
            "paging": false

        });
```

help:

[scrollCollapse scrollX](https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollCollapse)